# Dynamic Linq query with multiple Where Average

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I can get my average rating value for specific result like below:

```
var result1 = items.Where(x => x.Ratings.Average(y => y.MyRate == 1));
var result2 = items.Where(x => x.Ratings.Average(y => y.MyRate == 2));
var result3 = items.Where(x => x.Ratings.Average(y => y.MyRate == 3));
...
```

- So **result1** contains only items with avg rating is 1
- So **result2** contains only items with avg rating is 2
- So **result3** contains only items with avg rating is 3
- ...

Now, I would like to be able to combine these queries. I mean for example to get items with avg rating of 2, 3 and 4 at the same time.

```
 var results = items.Where(x => x.Ratings.Average(y => y.MyRate == 2 ||
                                x.Ratings.Average(y => y.MyRate == 3 ||
                                x.Ratings.Average(y => y.MyRate == 4));
```

The solution above is not dynamic because 2, 3, 4 are fix.

So let's say I have variable ratings which is a list of rating values. How can I query all items with avg rating contained in this variable ?

```
List<int> ratings = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4};

var results = items.Where(x => x.Ratings.Average(y => y.MyRate in ratings)); <--- does not work
```

Comment: *does not work* it's throw an exception? have you tried this `var results = items.Where(x => x.Ratings.Average(y => ratings.Any(z => y.MyRate == z)))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested using `Linq Contains`

```
List<decimal> ratings = new List<decimal>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var result = items.Where(x => ratings.Contains(x.Ratings.Average(y => y.MyRate)));
```

Heres the classes I used for testing. The above query contains Toy Story 2 and 3 but not 4 as Toy Story 4's average is not in `ratings`

```
class Item
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
}

class Rating
{
  public decimal MyRate { get; set; }
}
```

With the following initialization code

```
var items = new List<Item>
  {
    new Item  //MyRate average = 1
    {
      Name = "Toy Story 2",
      Ratings = new List<Rating>
      {
        new Rating { MyRate = 1 },
        new Rating { MyRate = 1 },
        new Rating { MyRate = 1 }
      }
    },
    new Item  //MyRate average = 2
    {
      Name = "Toy Story 3",
      Ratings = new List<Rating>
      {
        new Rating { MyRate = 1 },
        new Rating { MyRate = 2 },
        new Rating { MyRate = 3 }
      }
    },
    new Item  //MyRate average = 1.33
    {
      Name = "Toy Story 4",
      Ratings = new List<Rating>
      {
        new Rating { MyRate = 1 },
        new Rating { MyRate = 1 },
        new Rating { MyRate = 2 }
      }
    }
  };
```